# Why aren't there compiler-generated swap() methods in C++0x?

Tags: c++, language-design, c++11

C++ compilers automatically generate copy constructors and copy-assignment operators. Why not `swap` too?

These days the preferred method for implementing the copy-assignment operator is the copy-and-swap idiom:

```
T& operator=(const T& other)
{
    T copy(other);
    swap(copy);
    return *this;
}
```

([ignoring the copy-elision-friendly form that uses pass-by-value](https://web.archive.org/web/20140205194657/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)).

This idiom has the advantage of being transactional in the face of exceptions (assuming that the `swap` implementation does not throw).  In contrast, the default compiler-generated copy-assignment operator recursively does copy-assignment on all base classes and data members, and that doesn't have the same exception-safety guarantees.

Meanwhile, implementing `swap` methods manually is tedious and error-prone:

1. To ensure that `swap` does not throw, it must be implemented for all non-POD members in the class and in base classes, in their non-POD members, etc.
2. If a maintainer adds a new data member to a class, the maintainer must remember to modify that class's `swap` method.  Failing to do so can  introduce subtle bugs.  Also, since `swap` is an ordinary method, compilers (at least none I know of) don't emit warnings if the `swap` implementation is incomplete.

Wouldn't it be better if the compiler generated `swap` methods automatically? Then the implicit copy-assignment implementation could leverage it.

The obvious answer probably is: the copy-and-swap idiom didn't exist when C++ was developed, and doing this now might break existing code.

Still, maybe people could opt-in to letting the compiler generate `swap` using the same syntax that C++0x uses for controlling other implicit functions:

```
void swap() = default;
```

and then there could be rules:

1. If there is a compiler-generated `swap` method, an implicit copy-assignment operator can be implemented using copy-and-swap.
2. If there is no compiler-generated `swap` method, an implicit copy-assignment operator would be implemented as before (invoking copy-assigment on all base classes and on all members).

Does anyone know if such (crazy?) things have been suggested to the C++ standards committee, and if so, what opinions committee members had?

Comment: I've wondered the same thing a number of times, especially since `swap` is usually implemented in term of `swapping` all the data members anyway, so it's much like `copy` or `assignment` and the new `move` versions.

Comment: In C++0x, `swap` should be something along the lines of `template <typename T> void swap(T& x, T& y) { T temp(std::move(x)); x = std::move(y); y = std::move(temp); }` which will essentially do what any custom written swap functions would do. I agree with your question, but custom swaps aren't really necessary anymore, with the introduction of r-value references. `std::swap` will work great.

Comment: I suspect the reason it's not in C++98 is that the only compiler-generated functions in C++ are there in order to make classes behave like C structs: you can declare them, destroy them and copy them. However useful a default `swap` or a default `operator<` might be (and both could be implemented by field-wise operations) the C++ standard wanted a minimum of default functions, so there's less to suppress if you don't want it. The C++0x `function = something` syntax could be a much better fit, since it's optional. You could in principle even have different options for safe and unsafe swaps.

Comment: @GMan: If I'm not mistaken, std::move will benefit you only if T implements move constructor and move assignment (accepting parameter as `&&`). (And it seems, these might not be generated by the compiler for you, either.) If not then it will be back to good old copying and assigning.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer; go ahead and re-comment there, I think. Leave this comment section for question comments. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is in addition to Terry's answer.

The reason we had to make `swap` functions in C++ prior to 0x is because the general free-function `std::swap` was less efficient (and less versatile) than it could be. It made a copy of a parameter, then had two re-assignments, then released the essentially wasted copy. Making a copy of a heavy-weight class is a waste of time, when we as programmers know all we really need to do is swap the internal pointers and whatnot.

However, rvalue-references relieve this completely. In C++0x, `swap` is implemented as:

```
template <typename T>
void swap(T& x, T& y)
{
    T temp(std::move(x));
    x = std::move(y);
    y = std::move(temp);
}
```

This makes much more sense. Instead of copying data around, we are merely moving data around. This even allows non-copyable types, like streams, to be swapped. The draft of the C++0x standard states that in order for types to be swapped with `std::swap`, they must be rvalue constructable, and rvalue assignable (obviously).

This version of `swap` will essentially do what any custom written swap function would do. Consider a class we'd normally write `swap` for (such as this "dumb" vector):

```
struct dumb_vector
{
    int* pi; // lots of allocated ints

    // constructors, copy-constructors, move-constructors
    // copy-assignment, move-assignment
};
```

Previously, `swap` would make a redundant copy of all our data, before discarding it later. Our custom `swap` function would just swap the pointer, but can be clumsy to use in some cases. In C++0x, moving achieves the same end result. Calling `std::swap` would generate:

```
dumb_vector temp(std::move(x));
x = std::move(y);
y = std::move(temp);
```

Which translates to:

```
dumb_vector temp;
temp.pi = x.pi; x.pi = 0; // temp(std::move(x));
x.pi = y.pi; y.pi = 0; // x = std::move(y);
y.pi = temp.pi; temp.pi = 0; // y = std::move(temp);
```

The compiler will of course get rid of redundant assignment's, leaving:

```
int* temp = x.pi;
x.pi = y.pi;
y.pi = temp;
```

Which is *exactly* what our custom `swap` would have made in the first place. So while prior to C++0x I would agree with your suggestion, custom `swap`'s aren't really necessary anymore, with the introduction of rvalue-references. `std::swap` will work perfectly in any class that implements move functions.

In fact, I'd argue implementing a `swap` function should become bad practice. Any class that would need a `swap` function would also need rvalue functions. But in that case, there is simply no need for the clutter of a custom `swap`. Code size does increase (two ravlue functions versus one `swap`), but rvalue-references don't just apply for swapping, leaving us with a positive trade off. (Overall faster code, cleaner interface, slightly more code, no more `swap` ADL hassle.)

As for whether or not we can `default` rvalue functions, I don't know. I'll look it up later or maybe someone else can chime in, but that would sure be helpful. :)

Even so, it makes sense to allow `default` rvalue functions instead of `swap`. So in essence, as long as they allow `= default` rvalue functions, your request has already been made. :)

EDIT: I did a bit of searching, and the proposal for `= default` move was proposal [`n2583`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2583.html). According to [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2869.html) (which I don't know how to read very well), it was "moved back." It is listed under the section titled "Not ready for C++0x, but open to resubmit in future ". So looks like it won't be part of C++0x, but may be added later.

Somewhat disappointing. :(

EDIT 2: Looking around a bit more, I found this: [Defining Move Special Member Functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2953.html) which is much more recent, and does look like we can default `move`. Yay!

Comment: That makes sense. I haven't quite wrapped my head around the new rvalue reference stuff and suspected that might be a factor.  From what little I've read, it does sound like classes will need to explicitly implement a move-constructor, which would have similar maintenance burdens as implementing `swap`, unless there's a way to opt-in to an implicit definition with `... = default`.  I suppose even if there isn't, at least compilers might have an easier time generating warnings for incomplete implementations.

Comment: @james Yea, actually more of a burden since you need a move-constructor and move-assignment operator. Probably a good trade-off for all the other things rvalue-references provide. I really hope we can make `= default` r-value functions.

Comment: Do rvalue constructors and assignments have to be nothrow, or is it just strongly recommended (to get a nothrow `std::swap` for your class)? For instance if you have as a member a legacy class with no rvalue ctor, then you might be tempted to write an rvalue ctor that moves most of the data but copies that bit. That's death for the default swap implementation you give, it wouldn't necessarily even be strongly-safe, let alone nothrow. So unless I've missed something cunning, you need to implement swap yourself, to call swap on the legacy member, bad practice or not.

Comment: @Steve: I don't have the article on me, but from what I remember it seems it's only strongly recommended.

Comment: Defaulting move makes for interesting pitfalls that are similar to, but distinctly different from defaulting the copy contructor.

Comment: Quite reasonable, with one big gotcha. `operator=` can be implemented in terms of copy/move-constructor and `swap` member function, and I usually do this. See Item 11 of *Effective C++*.

Comment: @GManNickG To my understanding, **there is a difference between custom `swap` and `std::swap`** in the discussed case. `dumb_vector` calls `delete` in its destructor, even for _moved-from_ objects (this deletes null pointer). A compiler might have problem to optimize out these `delete`s (if it's even possible), see https://godbolt.org/g/E84ud4. `std::swap` invokes 3 times `delete`, while custom `swap` not a single one. **Isn't this a valid reason to provide custom swap even for classes that support move semantics?**

Comment: I measured the case with _unifying assignment operator_.  With dedicated _move assignment operator_, the effect is the very same, since `delete` need to be invoked inside its body (2x) and then once in destructor when applying `std::swap`.

Answer (score 11):

**swap, when used by STL algorithms, is a free function**. There is a default swap implementation: `std::swap`. It does the obvious. You seem to be under the impression that if you add a swap member function to your data type, STL containers and algorithms will find it and use it. This isn't the case.

You're supposed to specialize std::swap (in the namespace next to your UDT, so it's found by ADL) if you can do better. It is idiomatic to just have it defer to a member swap function.

While we're on the subject, it is also idiomatic in C++0x (in as much as is possible to have idioms on such a new standard) to implement rvalue constructors as a swap.

And yes, in a world where a member swap was the language design instead of a free function swap, this would imply that we'd need a swap operator instead of a function - or else primitive types (int, float, etc) couldn't be treated generically (as they have no member function swap). So why didn't they do this? You'd have to ask the committee members for sure - but I'm 95% certain the reason is the committee has long preferred library implementions of features whenever possible, over inventing new syntax to implement a feature. The syntax of a swap operator would be weird, because unlike =, +, -, etc, and all the other operators, there is no algebraic operator everyone is familiar with for "swap".

C++ is syntactically complex enough. They go to great lengths to not add new keywords or syntax features whenever possible, and only do so for very good reasons (lambdas!).

Comment: user defined type, argument dependent lookup, what the f**k

Comment: I'm not under any such impression.  I'm not talking about the freestanding `std::swap` function or about STL containers or algorithms at all, just about providing automatic `swap` member functions to objects, because it's easier for the compiler to do that than humans.  That said, I realize that just providing the member function wouldn't allow for consistent syntax, so if consistency is needed, it'd probably need, say, its own operator.

Comment: How about inventing a new operator `<->` for swap? :)

Comment: There's **gotta** be an ANSI symbol character left that C++ isn't using. Let's see... `` @ $. Digraphs? The dollar sign kinda looks like an S ($WAP).

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know if such (crazy?) things have been suggested to the C++ standards committee

Send an email to Bjarne. He knows all of this stuff and usually replies within a couple of hours.

Comment: Or, much better, post the question to Usenet on comp.std.c++ which is the main public discussion point for standard C++ and the standardisation processes.

Answer (score 1):

Is even compiler-generated move constructor/assignment planned (with the **default** keyword)?

> If there is a compiler-generated swap
>   method, an implicit copy-assignment
>   operator can be implemented using
>   copy-and-swap.

Even though the idiom leaves the object unchanged in case of exceptions, doesn't this idiom, by requiring the creation of a third object, make chances of failure greater in the first place?

There might also be performance implications (copying might be more expensive than "assigning") which is why I don't see such complicated functionality being left to be implemented by the compiler.

Generally I don't overload operator= and I don't worry about this level of exception safety: I don't wrap individual assignments into try blocks - what would I do with the most likely `std::bad_alloc` at that point? - so I wouldn't care if the object, before they end up destroyed anyway, remained in the original state or not. There may be of course specific situations where you might indeed need it, but I don't see why the principle of "you don't pay for what you don't use" should be given up here.

Comment: "you don't pay for what you don't use". If you never catch exceptions, and never write destructors which assume any objects are in a valid state, then you don't need exception guarantees. Other users of your classes might catch exceptions sometimes, and do things in destructors. They need exception guarantees. Unfortunately it's not possible always to provide exception guarantees so that you never pay if you don't use them. Fortunately if your class holds resources, and on assignment would have to free the old resource and allocate a new one, then CAS is no extra expense.