# The purpose behind empty struct?

Tags: c++, pointers

Declarations of auto_ptr from C++ Standard Library

```
namespace std {

template <class Y> struct auto_ptr_ref {};


template <class X>
class auto_ptr {
public:
    typedef X element_type;

    // 20.4.5.1 construct/copy/destroy:
    explicit           auto_ptr(X* p =0) throw();
                       auto_ptr(auto_ptr&) throw();
    template <class Y> auto_ptr(auto_ptr<Y>&) throw();

    auto_ptr&                      operator=(auto_ptr&) throw();
    template <class Y> auto_ptr&   operator=(auto_ptr<Y>&) throw();
    auto_ptr&                      operator=(auto_ptr_ref<X>) throw();

    ~auto_ptr() throw();

    // 20.4.5.2 members:
    X&     operator*() const throw();
    X*     operator->() const throw();
    X*     get() const throw();
    X*     release() throw();
    void   reset(X* p =0) throw();

    // 20.4.5.3 conversions:
                                auto_ptr(auto_ptr_ref<X>) throw();
    template <class Y> operator auto_ptr_ref<Y>() throw();
    template <class Y> operator auto_ptr<Y>() throw();
};
```

}

I don't understand the purpose of this part:

```
template <class Y> struct auto_ptr_ref {};
```

Without declaring any variable, how can these be valid:

```
auto_ptr&                      operator=(auto_ptr_ref<X>) throw();
```

and these too:

```
auto_ptr(auto_ptr_ref<X>) throw();
    template <class Y> operator auto_ptr_ref<Y>() throw();
```

**Edit:** and also (I just notice) I don't understand how the "operator" are used for the last two lines. Isn't the syntax something like "return-type operatoroperand;", where is the return type? operand?

Comment: ah i simply never know about that though (still new to here)

Comment: @user385261: When you are new to a website, read their FAQ. It's not there for kicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google search for "auto_ptr_ref" reveals [this detailed explanation](http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/auto_ptr.html).

I don't quite get that explanation, but looks like it is for the following. Without that trick you could pass an `auto_ptr` into a function that would get ownership of the object and assign your variable to a null pointer. With the extra class trick above you will get a compile error in such case.

Answer (score 3):

You've copied the text from the wikipedia entry on `auto_ptr`, didn't you? This is only the **public interface** to `auto_ptr` and co., not an excerpt from an implementation. They left the `auto_ptr_ref` body empty in the article to indicate, that there is noting inside for a user of a library.

The last two lines here:

```
 template <class Y> operator auto_ptr_ref<Y>() throw();
 template <class Y> operator auto_ptr<Y>() throw();
```

are conversion operators. The syntax of conversion operators differs a little, because it makes no sense to declare the return type of a converion operator (it's the name already!), so you don't write `int operator int();` but just `operator int();`

If you need a discussion how auto_ptr_ref is used in auto_ref, SO has a couple of them. For example here:
[what is auto_ptr_ref, what it achieves and how it achieves it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121844/what-is-auto-ptr-ref-what-it-achieves-and-how-it-achieves-it)