# Can you give me an example when auto_ptr_ref is really necessary?

Tags: c++

I would like to understand better the mechanics and the issues behind creating library and I have decided to start from the std::auto_ptr.
I am familiar with the syntax and the usage, however I am trying to understand the implementation details. I have implemented my version of the auto_ptr and it looks like this:

```
#ifndef _AUTO_PTR_H
#define _AUTO_PTR_H

namespace test
{    
    template<typename T>
    class auto_ptr
    {
        public:
            //ctor, dtor, copy ctor and assignment
            explicit auto_ptr(T* ptr = 0) throw() 
                : ptr_(ptr) {}

            auto_ptr(auto_ptr& other) throw()
                :ptr_(other.release()) {}

            auto_ptr<T>& operator=(auto_ptr<T>& other)
            {
                reset(other.release());
                return *this;
            }

            template<typename U>
            auto_ptr<T>& operator=(auto_ptr<U>& other) throw()
            {
                reset(other.release());
                return *this;
            }

            template<typename U>
            auto_ptr(auto_ptr<U>& other) throw() 
                : ptr_(other.release()) {}

            //member
            ~auto_ptr() throw() { delete ptr_; }

            T& operator*() const throw() { return *ptr_; }

            T* operator->() const throw() { return ptr_; }

            T* get() const throw() { return ptr_; }         

            T* release() throw()
            { 
                T* temp = ptr_;
                ptr_ = 0;
                return temp;
            }

            void reset(T* ptr = 0) throw()
            {
                if (ptr_ != ptr)
                {
                    delete ptr_;
                    ptr_ = ptr;
                }
            }

        private:
            T* ptr_;
    };
}

#endif
```

My class is doing pretty much the job then I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121844/what-is-auto-ptr-ref-what-it-achieves-and-how-it-achieves-it) and it is clear why auto_ptr_ref is there for. However I would like to have an actual example when the auto_ptr behaves differently without add auto_ptr_ref.

My implementation works correctly with this functions:

```
template <typename T>
test::auto_ptr<T> source()
{
    return test::auto_ptr<T>(new T());
}

template <typename T>
void sink(test::auto_ptr<T> bye)
{
}

template <typename T>
void useButNotSink(const test::auto_ptr<T> seeYouLater)
{
    std::cout << *seeYouLater << std::endl;
}
```

With this test program:

```
test::auto_ptr<double> copyConstructed(source<double>());

std::cout << *copyConstructed << std::endl;
std::cout << copyConstructed.get() << std::endl;

test::auto_ptr<double> assigned(new double(10));
assigned = source<double>();

std::cout << *assigned << std::endl;
std::cout << assigned.get() << std::endl;
*assigned = 2044;

std::cout << *assigned << std::endl;
useButNotSink(assigned);
sink(assigned);
std::cout << assigned.get() << std::endl;
```

I am sure I am missing something,can you give me an example where the auto_ptr_ref struct and the conversion operators are mandatory to get the correct behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Are you by any chance using an MSVC compiler with settings that allows a temporary to bind to a non-const reference in `auto_ptr<T>& operator=(auto_ptr<T>& other)`?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010, but I thought it was irrelevant :-(

Comment: @Bo Persson do you know how to switch off this extension?

Comment: @Allesandro - There is "Disable language extensions" /Za, which breaks most everything else.  :-(  Otherwise if you use a high enough warning level, like /W4, it will warn you that you are using an extension.

Comment: @Bo Persson, thanks I will raise my warning level ;-)

Comment: I have a problem with the assignment operator. It does not provide the ["Strong Exception Guarantee"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106586/what-are-the-principles-guiding-your-exception-handling-policy/106749#106749) (which std::auto_ptr provides). The call to reset() calls delete which may throw thus causing you to leak the pointer that you get from calling release().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your very first line

```
test::auto_ptr<double> copyConstructed(source<double>());
```

is already non-compilable by any standard-compliant compiler. MSVC will allow it when the C++ language extensions are enabled. Disable the extensions and you will immediately realize the need for `auto_ptr_ref`.

The mechanics behind `auto_ptr_ref` was too complicated for MSVC 6.0, so in order to support some resemblance of full `std::auto_ptr` functionality that compiler had to rely on this compiler extension, i.e. allowing non-const references to be bound to temporary objects. The problem was fixed in later versions of the compiler, but this compiler extension remains enabled by default to this day.

Comment: I did, it makes much more sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be using compiler extension.  I don't see a copy constructor with const reference argument.  As you can't pass a temporary to a non const reference,

```
test::auto_ptr<double> copyConstructed(source<double>());
```

should fail to compile (the result of `source<double>()` being a temporary).

(Note that in C++0X, rvalue reference are a better mean to achieve the effect).

Comment: Hint: Visual C++ is *not* a standard-compliant compiler (and compiles that line).

Comment: @Jan, It isn't the only one.  SunCC does the same by default.  It was the rule a long time ago and compatibility is a stronger constraint for some compilers than others.  (I'd prefer an option allowing to get the non conformant but compatible behavior than needing an option to get the standard behavior).