# Why isn't there implicit or defaulted swap()?

Tags: c++, swap, language-design

The question is basically the same as the old [Why aren't there compiler-generated swap() methods in C++0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078515/why-arent-there-compiler-generated-swap-methods-in-c0x), but provides more recent context and asks for a more up-to-date answer.

If for some class `C` `swap(C&, C&)` is implemented much more efficiently than `std::swap<C>`, then each class `D` that contains `C` as a data member or inherits `C` must define its own `swap(D&, D&)` in order to benefit from `swap(C&, C&)`'s efficiency (`std::swap<D>` only calls `D`'s move constructor and move assignment operator, which in turn call `C`'s move operations). Then each class that contains a `D` data member or inherits `D` has to implement its own `swap()` for maximum efficiency, and so on.

The top answer to [Move semantics == custom swap function obsolete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416385/move-semantics-custom-swap-function-obsolete) states that a custom `swap()` can often be much faster. But writing even a trivial custom definition is error-prone: each base class and each data member has to be swapped; each newly-added base class or data member requires a modification of the custom `swap()`'s definition.

[n3746](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3746.pdf) proposes adding a new operator to replace the free `swap()` function. The proposal has been rejected because the committee felt that already implemented `swap()` overloads would be retained and called by new code for backwards compatibility. The coexistence of the swap operator and the free `swap()` function is considered undesirable. But is there a reason why the free `friend` `swap()` function cannot be implicitly generated or declared by the user as defaulted? For example:

```cpp
class D : public Base
{
public:
    friend void swap(D&, D&) = default;
private:
    C c_;
    std::vector<int> v_;
    double r_;
};
```

The compiler could generate the following definition:

```cpp
void swap(D& a, D& b) noexcept(...)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(static_cast<Base&>(a), static_cast<Base&>(b));
    swap(a.c_, b.c_);
    swap(a.v_, b.v_);
    swap(a.r_, b.r_);
}
```

Here `noexcept(...)` stands for `noexcept(true)` if swapping each subobject is `noexcept(true)`; `noexcept(false)` otherwise.

The compiler could implicitly declare and generate `swap()` for a class that has no user-declared copy/move constructor/assignment operators. This is somewhat risky due to the absence of `std::swap()`'s strong exception guarantee. But the implicitly-generated copy and move special members lack strong exception guarantee too, so this shouldn't be much of a problem.

The compiler-generated `swap()` would get rid of error-prone custom boilerplate definitions and speed up swapping objects of classes and structs, for which no custom `swap()` is implemented. Is there a technical or a philosophical reason why this feature hasn't been proposed for the C++ standard? Is the feature relatively unimportant? Or is this an oversight/omission?

Comment: The proposal for swap already covers the case where move semantics (move constructors) is directly used in std::swap so an extra constructor is not really needed. Personally I think having std::swap is good enough and in code it clearly shows your intent which I think is also important. Also getting a proposal to extend stl or the language accepted needs a lot of detail and work, check http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm and you can see how much detail is involved in "simple" swapping

Comment: Sure, `std::swap` is good enough for some types, but not for types `C` that have expensive move constructors (e.g. if each object always contains allocated data as an invariant), and consequently not for types that contain `C` as a subobject. The implicit/defaulted `swap()` is an addition rather than a replacement for `std::swap`, and I think it shows one's intent as clearly as `std::swap` does.

Comment: If it would be compiler generated, then I think that it should be deleted if any sub object swap would throw.